# nagios enable_notifications not working

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I am trying to disable all notifications on my nagios core server. Initially I changed nagios.conf with enable_notifications=0. It worked and when I go to GUI, I was able to see red notification saying "notifications are disabled". Then I reverted changes. It worked perfectly and red message from UI was disappeared.

After that, from GUI, I went to System->Process Info->Disable Notification. Command seemed success but I was unable to see red message on GUI so I went again System->Process Info->Enable Notification. After that I am unable to disable notifications. Even if I change nagios.conf and restart service, It doesn't make any difference. Neither it display red message on GUI nor notifications stops. Can you please help me understand

1. Why this behavior?
2. How to reset effect of any GUI command (like enable/disable from GUI) if executed

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click System->Process Info->Enable Notification it sets a program wide "state" value that overrides the config values.

All program wide "state" values take precedence over configuration values.

To reset all the runtime values edit the nagios.cfg and set the following

```
use_retained_program_state=0
```

Then restart nagios

Here is a link to more information on use_retained_program_state

https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/configmain.html#use_retained_program_state